# Smoothing with non-regular observations

Tags: smoothing, unevenly-spaced-time-series

If we have data that changes continuously in time, and we sample this data at regular intervals - i.e. we get samples $x_0$, $x_1$, $\dots$, where the time $\Delta t$ between taking samples $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ is independent of $i$ - then there are a number of simple smoothing approaches: we can take a moving average, or we can use exponential smoothing, etc.

However, if our samples are at irregular intervals - i.e. we get samples $(x_0, t_0)$, $(x_1, t_1)$, $\dots$, where $t_0 < t_1 < t_2 < \cdots$, but $t_{i+1} - t_i$ is not constant - then both the moving average and exponential smoothing will be biased towards time periods where there are more measurements.

Are there any good ways to avoid this kind of bias, or, alternatively, any comparably simple smoothing algorithms for this situation that avoid this bias?

Comment: Welcome to our site. I imagine the answer ought to depend on the purpose of smoothing.  For exploratory data analysis, *e.g.*, John Tukey recommended separately smoothing the sequence of $(x_i)$ *and* the sequence of the $(t_i)$ and reassembling the smoothed values.  You can read about this in his book, *EDA.* But for modeling and forecasting you might get answers about Dynamic Time Warping, Gaussian processes, and many other approaches.  Thus, it would behoove you to edit your post to supply a little more information about your goals and your models of your process.